# Speed up index in large matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a large matrix (as class Matrix) in R. It is sparse (only containing 01).

What I do is (if M is the Matrix)

```
j<-list()
for(i in 1:dim(M)[1]){
    which(M[i,]==1)->j[[i]]
}
```

this is normally fast but on such a large matrix(dim 1.7 Mil to 5000) it is very slow. I just cant believe that there is no faster way to obtain the indices of those cols that are 1 in every row....

Comment: Having a "Matrix" you could use `summary(M)` and, then, `split($j, $i)` or, probably more efficient, `split(rep(seq_len(ncol(M)), diff(M@p)), M@i + 1L)`

Answer (score 2):

Using the example by @zx8754

```
M <- matrix(c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1), 4)
```

we can define an auxiliary matrix that contains the row and column indices of the entries equal to 1:

```
oneMat <- which(M==1, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

From this auxiliary matrix we can create a list that contains the column numbers that are equal to one in each row with

```
oneList <- lapply(1:nrow(M), function(x) oneMat[oneMat[,1] == x, 2])
#[[1]] 
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 3
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 2 3
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 2 3
```

If the matrix `M` is large and sparse, the matrix `oneMat` should be much smaller than `M`. In that case I think that the `lapply()` loop used in the second step could lead to a speedup with respect to the `for` loop described in the OP.

---

After some tests, I regretfully have to admit that this answer is particularly slow. The solution by @ColonelBeauvel is the winner:

```
j <- list()
set.seed(123)
M <- matrix(rbinom(1e5,1,0.01),ncol=100)
library(microbenchmark)
f_which_and_lappy <- function(x) {oneMat <- which(x==1, arr.ind=TRUE); 
           lapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) oneMat[oneMat[,1] == i, 2])}
f_only_apply <- function(x) {apply(x, 1, function(i) which(i == 1))}
f_with_data.frame <- function(x) {with(data.frame(which(!!x, arr.ind=T)), split(col, row))}
f_OP <- function(x) {for(i in 1:dim(x)[1]){which(x[i,]==1)->j[[i]]}}
res <- microbenchmark(
  f_which_and_lappy(M),
  f_only_apply(M),
  f_with_data.frame(M), 
  f_OP(M),times=1000L)
#> res
#Unit: microseconds
#                 expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval  cld
# f_which_and_lappy(M) 11063.170 11254.032 12090.9506 11351.1830 11570.662  31313.48  1000    d
#      f_only_apply(M)  3204.572  3359.410  4117.4971  3456.3960  3610.945  25352.35  1000  b  
# f_with_data.frame(M)   739.556   811.906   912.4726   918.0315   946.700  18623.77  1000 a   
#              f_OP(M)  5642.639  5854.751  6955.9980  5969.3685  6151.209 148847.22  1000   c
```

Comment: is it possible to benchamrk - it really still takes quite a bit of time - is there soem way to print the index at whcih it currently is?

Comment: To display the current row, you might try `oneList <- lapply(1:nrow(M), function(x){cat("x=",x,"\r"); oneMat[oneMat[,1] == x, 2]})`

Comment: hi that is even slower  than the solution that I proposed above. I really dont know why but it does 1 row per 20 sec or so ... is there no chance to get it a bit faster?

Comment: The output with `cat` slows it down. However, I'm not sure that the solution is inherently faster. I'll try to make benchmark tests.

Comment: thanks a lot...but it is just really slow - it is definitely because it is not a normal matrix but a Matrix - as in a sparse matrix

Comment: You are right. It is *really* slow. See the benchmarks that I have added.

Comment: the issue is that for the fast solution I get the Error in which(!(!M), arr.ind = T) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'which': Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
 error

Answer (score 2):

I would rather opt for a vectorized approach,and use `split` instead of these apply/lapply family functions:

```
M  = matrix(c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1), 4)

with(data.frame(which(!!M, arr.ind=T)), split(col, row))
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3

#$`2`
#[1] 1 3

#$`3`
#[1] 2 3

#$`4`
#[1] 2 3
```

Comment: any chance to circumvent the Error in which(!(!M), arr.ind = T) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'which': Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
 error here? and still make it fast? It is not a normal matrix but a Matrix

Comment: you posted `which(!(!M), arr.ind = T)` whereas it is simply `which(!!M, arr.ind = T) `

Comment: so I get with(data.frame(which(!!M, arr.ind=T)), split(col, row))->j



Error in which(!(!M), arr.ind = T) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'which': Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105

Comment: if you change `which(!!M, arr.ind = T)` to `which(M==1, arr.ind = T)` ? it is certainly due to the sparse matrix format, you can try converting it of a matrix if it does not take too much time ...otherwise I will look at it later but there is certainly a way to handle which with sparse matrix.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** after comments:

```
apply(M, 1, function(i) which(i == 1))

# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 3
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 2 3
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 2 3
```

Try this example:

```
#data
M <- matrix(c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1), 4)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    0    1
# [3,]    0    1    1
# [4,]    0    1    1

# index of rows with all ones
which(rowSums(M == 1) == ncol(M))
# [1] 1

# index of cols with all ones
which(colSums(M == 1) == nrow(M))
# [1] 3
```

Comment: hi - sorry it is not about finding the row will all 1- it is about finding the 1 in a specific row - there are no rows in which all values are 1 - i just need the index where they are 1

Comment: Then just try `which(M == 1)`.

Comment: in your example , I need for row 2 the results 1 and 3, for row 3, 2 and 3 for row 4 2 and 3

Comment: but that provides a Matrix back - which I then need to parse again - right?

Comment: Hi so which(M==1) does work but it gives me the position in the Matrix in terms of a count of the cell

Comment: @kutyw let's say we have that output, what is the next step?

Comment: @kutyw Maybe: `apply(M, 1, function(i) which(i == 1))`?

Comment: when I try in the Matrix object I just get Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105